# side by side table

Tags: tables

I am trying to figure out how to put these tables side by side (or at least in a proper form)

```
\begin{table} 
\caption{Initial measurement of photoresist step heights for $15$ and $30$ wafers ($A^\circ$)}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{center}      
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} %% this creates two columns
%% |l|l| to left justify each column entry
%% |c|c| to center each column entry
%% use of \rule[]{}{} below opens up each row
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $1$  & 1.4725   \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $3$  & 1.4725  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $6$  & 1.495  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $14$  &  1.492 \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $16$  &   1.465\\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $20$  & 1.2525 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Post etch measurement of photoresist step heights for $15$ (4 mins) and $30$ (6 mins) wafers ($A^\circ$)}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{center}       
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} %% this creates two columns
%% |l|l| to left justify each column entry
%% |c|c| to center each column entry
%% use of \rule[]{}{} below opens up each row
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $1$  & 1.5875   \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $3$  & 1.575  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $6$  & 1.5925  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $14$  &  1.66 \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $16$  &   1.63\\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $20$  & 1.4625 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} 
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table} [h]
\caption{Post SPM treatment ($nm$)}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{center}       
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} %% this creates two columns
%% |l|l| to left justify each column entry
%% |c|c| to center each column entry
%% use of \rule[]{}{} below opens up each row
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $1$  & 142.5   \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $3$  & 142.5  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $6$  & 132.5  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $14$  &  190 \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $16$  &   197.5\\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    wafer $20$  & 192.5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} 
\FloatBarrier
```

Second Part of question :

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Measurement of oxide thickness for blank wafer before etch (pre etch)} \label{tab:1}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{center}      
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} %% this creates two columns
%% |l|l| to left justify each column entry
%% |c|c| to center each column entry
%% use of \rule[]{}{} below opens up each row
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    center & 5114 $A^\circ$   \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    top  & 5236 $A^\circ$   \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    right & 5196$A^\circ$ \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    bottom  &  5156$A^\circ$  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    left  &   5211$A^\circ$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Measurement of oxide thickness for blank wafer after etch (post etch)} \label{tab:2}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{center}      
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} %% this creates two columns
%% |l|l| to left justify each column entry
%% |c|c| to center each column entry
%% use of \rule[]{}{} below opens up each row
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    center & 3088 $A^\circ$   \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    top  & 3154 $A^\circ$   \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    right & 3133$A^\circ$ \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    bottom  &  3043$A^\circ$  \\
\hline
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}    left  &   3112$A^\circ$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your posting, but relevant for good typography: I assume that `$A^\circ$` is supposed to denote "angstrom". If that's the case, you really should write it as "\AA" in text mode: the "ring" belongs on top of the uprightshape "A", not to the side of a slanted "A".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `floatrow` package lets you easily align  captions by their top lines. No need to add invisible rules to add some padding to the rows:  with the `cellspace` package, you can define minimal vertical spacing between a row and the above and below cells.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, floatrow,cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hskip1.6em}
\begin{document}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\floatsetup{floatrowsep=mysep, capposition=TOP, captionskip =1.5ex}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
  \begin{floatrow}[3]
    \ttabbox[1.5\FBwidth]{\caption{Initial measurement of photoresist step heights for $15$ and $30$ wafers (\AA)}
      \label{tab:fontsa}}%
    {\begin{tabular}{|Sl|l|}
      \hline
      wafer $1$ & 1.4725 \\ \hline
      wafer $3$ & 1.4725 \\ \hline
      wafer $6$ & 1.495 \\ \hline
      wafer $14$ & 1.492 \\ \hline
      wafer $16$ & 1.465 \\ \hline
      wafer $20$ & 1.2525 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}}%
    \hfill%
    \ttabbox[1.5\FBwidth]{\caption{Post etch measurement of photoresist step heights for $15$ (4 mins) and $30$ (6 mins) wafers (\AA)}%
      \label{tab:fontsb}}%
    {\begin{tabular}{|Sl|l|}
      \hline
      wafer $1$ & 1.5875 \\ \hline
      wafer $3$ & 1.575 \\ \hline
      wafer $6$ & 1.5925 \\ \hline
      wafer $14$ & 1.66\\ \hline
      wafer $16$ & 1.63 \\ \hline
      wafer $20$ & 1.4625 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}}
    %
    \ttabbox{\caption{Post SPM treat\-ment ($nm$)} \label{tab:fonts3}}
    { \begin{tabular}{|Sl|l|} %% this creates two columns
      %% |l|l| to left justify each column entry
      %% |c|c| to center each column entry
      %% use of \rule[]{}{} below opens up each row
      \hline
      wafer $1$ & 142.5 \\ \hline
      wafer $3$ & 142.5 \\ \hline
      wafer $6$ & 132.5 \\ \hline
      wafer $14$ & 190 \\ \hline
      wafer $16$ & 197.5 \\ \hline
      wafer $20$ & 192.5 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}}%
  \end{floatrow}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Oh! yes, you're right. I've changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do you like to have something like this:

[image]

Above picture is generated by:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Initial measurement of photoresist step heights for $15$ and $30$ wafers ($A^\circ$)}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format=2.5]|}
    \hline
wafer $1$   &   1.4725   \\ \hline
wafer $3$   &   1.4725   \\ \hline
wafer $6$   &   1.495    \\ \hline
wafer $14$  &   1.492    \\ \hline
wafer $16$  &   1.465    \\ \hline
wafer $20$  &   1.2525   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Post etch measurement of photoresist step heights for $15$ (4 mins) and $30$ (6 mins) wafers ($A^\circ$)}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format=2.5]|}
    \hline
wafer $1$   &   1.5875   \\ \hline
wafer $3$   &   1.575    \\ \hline
wafer $6$   &   1.5925   \\ \hline
wafer $14$  &   1.66     \\ \hline
wafer $16$  &   1.63     \\ \hline
wafer $20$  &   1.4625   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Post SPM treatment ($nm$)}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format=4.2]|}
    \hline
wafer $1$   &   142.5   \\ \hline
wafer $3$   &   142.5   \\ \hline
wafer $6$   &   132.5   \\ \hline
wafer $14$  &   190     \\ \hline
wafer $16$  &   197.5   \\ \hline
wafer $20$  &   192.5   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table} 
    \end{document}
```

In your MWE the role of `\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}` is replaced it by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}`, which made similar height of cells as it was before. From question is not clear to me what you like to obtain with mix of "mini pages", "center" environments and use of `\centering`. I clear all this codes and form three `minipages` in which are  tables centered by `\centering` command.

Beside this I add package `siunitx` and use its `S` column type for nicer typing of numbers in your tables.

*Note*: I didn't bother with caption formatting.

Addendum: Lets do the do-it-for-me service for added second part of question (I do this since I'm happy that after few hour of repairing my MikTeX installation it works again as desired ... ). The code is:

```
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Measurement of oxide thickness for blank wafer before etch (pre etch)} \label{tab:1}
    \label{tab:fonts}
\begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format=5.0,
                     table-space-text-post=\si{\angstrom}]<{\si{\angstrom}\ }|}
    \hline
center  &   5114    \\  \hline
top     &   5236    \\  \hline
right   &   5196    \\  \hline
bottom  &   5156    \\  \hline
left    &   5211    \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Measurement of oxide thickness for blank wafer after etch (post etch)} \label{tab:2}
\label{tab:fonts}
\begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format=5.0,
                     table-space-text-post=\si{\angstrom}]<{\si{\angstrom}\ }|}
    \hline
center  &   3088    \\  \hline
top     &   3154    \\  \hline
right   &   3133    \\  \hline
bottom  &   3043    \\  \hline
left    &   3112    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

In above code I assume, that $A^\circ$ mean unit Angstrom. I use standardizired notation for it as defined insiunitx` package (this was not considered in the first table).

Result:

[image]

Comment: @ zarko I do not know where I have an error, but see my original question - second part is added. I tried to put them in side by side as well.

Comment: @Mohammad , second part of your questions contain the same errors as the first part, which is corrected in my answer. You need to reformat its code on the same way as I do for your first part (all should be in one `table` environment, erase all `\begin{center}` and`end{center}`, between `minipages` cannot be empty lines ..). Please try to make analysis of my answer and do the same. Temporary I can't help you since just now I try to reinstall my MikTeX ...

Comment: @Mohammad, I format the second part of your question.

Comment: @ Zarko, thank you for very informative answer. I could easily practice that. if you interested to question, please upvote that.

Comment: @Mohammad, I do not only edit your question, I also upvote it. Well, you not accept my answer, however ask me to upgrade it for your latter addition to question. Now I'm a bit confused, why you not ask for this service author of accepted answer? Apparently you will not use my addendum to my answer ... I will erase it.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. :-)

Comment: @Mico, because of addendum, which I erase? Than I will try to recover it :-)

Comment: It's a good answer with or without the addendum. Very good catch on the `A^\circ` business, for sure. I'd undelete the addendum. :-)

Comment: @ Zarko, I thought I accepted your answers. Thanks for mentioning this. I just forgot that.